Android Audio Routing fails to route to the correct source when integrated with Agora Voice call SDK
Our app's expectations: To switch the audio route from bluetooth to speaker or earpiece when bluetooth is connected with the device.
We have audio routing options showing in an UI: Speaker, Earpiece, Bluetooth (if it is connected with device).
Previously, I was using Agora's setEnableSpeakerPhone() to route the audio to earpiece or speaker and added bluetoothSco() and setCommunicationDevice() for routing it to bluetooth. But with this, agora functions clashes with Android default routing and when bluetooth is connected, then it is not allowing the route to transfer to earpiece or speaker, it is always on bluetooth.
Now, I am trying it with android's default routing only and disable all the code of Agora handling the route. Still I am facing the problem with routing.
If anyone has faced similar kind of issue with any third party, please let me know the solution.

Please make a question...
I see that you explain your situation, but you need to ask a question.
